# Not able to do async dispatch to consumer and understand how "prefetch limit" is relevant

Tags: asynchronous, jms, activemq-classic

My understanding was that default behavior of ActiveMQ is to do async dispatch of messages to the consumers, but when I tried to test it by doing a `Thread.sleep(60000);` in my `MessageListener#onMessage()` then broker was not able to send queued messages until it received the acknowledgment from the dispatch of previous message.

So, then I tried to explicitly set the async flag, just in case, using `((ActiveMQConnectionFactory)connectionFactory).setDispatchAsync(true);` as mentioned [here](http://activemq.apache.org/consumer-dispatch-async.html) but still same behavior.

Is there a way in which I can make sure that my ActiveMQ broker doesn't get blocked if one of the consumer is taking long time, please note that I know and read about "slow consumers" but this is not what I want, I want a truly async dispatch where-in where broker sends the message doesn't wait for any acknowledgement/response.

---

**EDIT:**
I just read about [what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) and I am wondering that when broker is sending message synchronously to the consumer then what's the point of "prefetch limit"?

Comment: How did you understand this : then broker was not able to send queued messages until it received the acknowledgment from the dispatch of previous message.

Comment: Once the broker has dispatched a prefetch limit number of messages to a consumer it will not dispatch any more messages to that consumer until the consumer has acknowledged at least 50% of the prefetched messages, e.g., prefetch/2, that it received. When the broker has received said acknowledgements it will dispatch a further prefetch/2 number of messages to the consumer to 'top-up', as it were, its prefetch buffer, maybe it is a prefetch problem http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the default configuration, ActiveMQ is configured to use a dispatch thread per Queue - you can use set the optimizedDispatch property on the destination policy entry - [see configuring Queues](http://activemq.apache.org/scaling-queues.html).

set the  optimizedDispatch="true" in activemq.xml

optimizedDispatch :

**Default Value** : false

**Description** : Don't use a separate thread for dispatching from a Queue.

Note that by doing a Thread.sleep(60000); in the MessageListener#onMessage() when using a single consumer the dispatcher of the consumer cannot send another messages.

**UPDATE**

```
<destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry queue=">" optimizedDispatch="true"/>
              <policyEntries>
            <policyMap>
         <destinationPolicy>
```

queue=">" means all queues

---

**EDIT by OP (hagrawal):** To help future visitor to catch the concept quickly I am putting below the core concept in nut shell, please feel free to read all the comments below in order to know more. Many thanks to @HassenBennour for clarifying all this.

> If there are 2 consumers connected and messages getting produced then
>   it will do robin round message dispatching to those consumer, but
>   suppose no consumer is connected, broker got 4 messages enqueued, a
>   consumer got connected with 3 as prefetch limit then it will deliver 3
>   messages to the consumer and then wait, meanwhile if some other
>   consumer gets connected then it will immediately deliver 4th message
>   to that otherwise it will wait for acknowledgment of 1st message
>   before delivering 4th message to same consumer.

Comment: Can you give an example for its usage, whether it needs to be configured in broker or in producer/consumer and how, I tried to use like this `ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616?optimizedDispatch=true");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: And for your last comment, even communication is totally async then it doesn't matter what happens in `MessageListener#onMessage()`

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example, this must be added in activemq.xml to the broker and not on the consumer side

Comment: a consumer always has a local buffer of messages ready to process. The consumer uses the prefetch limit to size its prefetch message buffer. With default asynch configs and prefetch limit the broker dispatches max 1000 messages to the consumer which holds them in a local dispatcher asynchronously to the listener, the dispatcher dispatches the messages one by one to the listener and if the listener blocks the broker is not blocked but the dispatcher blocks because the call is in the same thread. What is the acknowledgement mode you use ?

Comment: It didn't work, I added the config as per your answer, even tried to change from `queue=">"` to `queue="my_queue_name"`, but my second message is not delivered until `Thread.sleep` is over. I have many reasons to believe otherwise, because (1.) suppose local dispatcher is getting blocked because of `Thread.sleep` and not the broker then when I got my second consumer (new connection) then it didn't get any message because my first consumer was clocking (2) if the broker is free and only local dispatcher is blocked because of `Thread.sleep` then why ActiveMQ GUI doesn't show 0 count for queue?

Comment: The second consumer cannot receive any messages if there is less than 1000 messages in the queue due to the prefetch limit as i said 1000 first messages are dispatched to the 1st consumer and if you have 2 messages and want the second consumer receive one of them change the prefetch limit to 1

Comment: Set the prefetch limit to 1 at the ConnectionFactory and retry

Comment: Ok, thanks, this was helpful. I think I have got it to a larger extend, please confirm me my understanding - **when prefetch limit is 1** then broker would deliver the message a consumer and would wait for its acknowledgment before delivering another message to the consumer, **but** it wouldn't block the broker to deliver next message to "another" consumer.

Comment: Now, lets say **when prefetch limit is 2** then broker will deliver 2 messages to consumer and would wait for acknowledgment of at least 1 message before delivering next set of message to same consumer **BUT** would also remain blocked and wouldn't be able to deliver messages to other consumers until it receives acknowledgment of at least 1 message from first consumer.

Comment: No other consumers are not blocked, if the prefetch limit is 2 and there is 2 consumers and 3 messages : if the first consumer has not acknowledged the first message of the 2 dispatched by the broker to him the 2nd consumer will receive the 3rd message

Comment: Ok, you are right, I did more tests please correct my understanding - if there are 2 consumers connected and messages getting produced then it will do robin round message dispatching to those consumer, but suppose no consumer is connected, broker got 4 messages enqueued, a consumer got connected with 3 as prefetch limit then it will deliver 3 messages to the consumer and then wait, meanwhile if some other consumer gets connected then it will immediately deliver 4th message to that otherwise it will wait for acknowledgment of 1st message before delivering 4th message to same consumer.

Comment: yep you got it!